# $\sum_{k=1}^n \lfloor kx \rfloor =$ ?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, number-theory, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Let $x$ be a positive real number and $n$ a positive integer , then how may we evaluate $\sum_{k=1}^n \lfloor kx \rfloor $ ?

If a closed form doesn't exist then can we at least find an asymptotic formula  for the sum ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Asymptotic is easy, $\lfloor kx\rfloor = kx - \{kx\}$.

Comment: Wouldn't you rather have that in the form $k\lfloor x\rfloor \leq \lfloor kx\rfloor \leq kx$?

Comment: You can get a rational aproximation of $x$ of the form $\frac{m}{n}$ where $m = \lfloor xn\rfloor$ so the sum becomes $m(n+1)$ aprox.

Answer (score 1):

If $x$ is irrational, then

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n} \lfloor kx \rfloor
= \sum_{k=1}^{n} kx - \sum_{k=1}^{n} \{ kx \}
= \frac{n(n+1)x}{2} - n \cdot \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \{ kx \}. $$

Since the sequence $( \{ kx \} )$ is equidistributed, we know that

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \{ kx \} = \int_{0}^{1} x \, dx = \frac{1}{2}. $$

Consequently we have the following asymptotics:

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n} \lfloor kx \rfloor = \tfrac{1}{2} x n^2 + \tfrac{1}{2}(x-1)n + o(n). $$

Answer (score 0):

TheGreatDuck,

For $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $x \in \mathbb{R}$ we have
$$ \lfloor nx \rfloor = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1} \lfloor x + \frac{i}{n} \rfloor $$